# CallBack not working on Galaxy Tab, but does work on all other devices

Tags: android, callback, webview, galaxy

I'm testing my app out on my brand new Galaxy Tab and I encountered something strange.

I have Twitter integration in my app. What it basically does is open a WebView and use Oauth to autheticate. After that it sends a CallBack back to my app with the secret token and there I use it for tweeting purposes. You can get more info about how I do this here: [CallBack after Twitter authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387631/callback-after-twitter-authentication)

This workes on all devices, but on the Galaxy Tab it doesn't go back to my app. In stead, it gives me the "Web page not available" page in the browser with the correct CallBack URL in the adresbar.

How come it doesn't work on the Galaxy Tab?

EDIT:

Could it be because the Galaxy Tab use their own browser that doesn't support CallBack?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised it works on *any* device... the callback is sent as the response to a normal HTTP request, i.e. a 302 redirect. This is not the same thing as a user click... I don't see that you can ever rely on the browser firing an Intent for a redirect.

Unless you quickly find a workaround I strongly suggest switching to [XAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth). It's a far better fit for mobile apps. Twitter's OAuth flow assumed a PC web browser every step of the way, which is always a horrible user experience on a mobile platform.

Comment: Unfortunately xAuth is no option for us.

Is it possible to make a custom webview inside my app as a workaround? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: You could try changing your callback URL to javascript:window.location="sosInternational:///HierBenIkNu". Suitably urlencoded of course, and with Javascript enabled in your WebView. That might force the browser to fire the intent.

Comment: Can we safely assume this is no longer a problem, i.e. the above suggestion worked? Damn but I hate it when people just disappear... >:-[

Comment: I didn't 'disappeared'. I appreciate your help (and from others) but I had a rough time this week with some deadlines..

I will look into this later on, but don't assosiate me with those other hit 'n runners.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter library works by inspecting the links which are being open in the webbrowser. One easiest way to check would be Place a breakpoint the code which implements the WebViewClient. If the break point hits on the function onLoadResource then there is some other bug or else what you are thinking is correct.